# Confused with parameter pack declaration, C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, parameters

Can anyone please explain what the following declaration means?

```
template<typename... T> void f2(std::vector<T*>...);
```

Does this mean that f2 accepts number of `std::vectors` with different pointer types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that f2 accepts number of std::vectors with different pointer types?

Yes!

```
template<typename... T> void f2(std::vector<T*>...) {}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int*> vi;
    std::vector<double*> vd;

    f2( vi, vd );
}
```

Hint:
If running gcc you can use:

```
template<typename... T> void f2(std::vector<T*>...) 
{   
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

which will output:

```
void f2(std::vector<T*>...) [with T = {int, double}]
```